# Zoom replacement for UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiscrollview

Due to a fairly complicated system that doesn't really warrant explaining for here, I need the zoom capabilities of a UIScrollView, however UIScrollView itself won't work in this situation; it's stopping some touch events from propagating that I need to propagate.

Are there any classes, either from Apple or third parties, that function similarly to the zooming capabilities of UIScrollView that I could try out as a replacement?

Comment: You can use a UIPinchGestureRecogizner.

Comment: Also do you need to zoom into an image?

Comment: Yeah I need to zoom into a UIView, with bouncing and all that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use a UIPinchGestureRecognizer. Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.techpaa.com/2011/03/pinch-zoom-using-uipinchgesturerecogniz.html) to teach how to do it.